# How to protect Docker (data-only) volumes from deletion?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-stack

I use to create Docker (data-only) volumes like this: `docker create -v /data/--name data-container busybox`

Then I use these volumes in *docker-stack* setups, transfer them to different hosts, export them to read out logs, do backups, ...

But from time to time it happens that someone (accidentally) cleans up Docker with `docker rm $(docker ps -qa)` which also deletes volume-container if they are not mounted.

This leads to a serious data lost (data since last backup), because there seems to be no (technical) way to protect data volumes from deletion. It is not posible to use `--filter "image!=busybox` or `--filter "name!=data"` or flag a volume/container as *undeletable*.

What is the best way to handle this problem? Only use bind-mounts? Cut off a team members finger when he deletes a volume? Any other suggestions?

Comment: you could keep the data in named volumes, they survive container deletion and are reattached when another container uses the same named volume. Create the volume with `docker volume create --name XX` then attach it with `docker run -v XX`. They should also survive `docker system prune` as there is a special flag to clean volumes

Comment: @zzanzare Goo point! I did not consider this before because once I used to push a initial state of volume-containers to our private Docker repository.

Now I use scripts to (re-)create volume-containers, so this could be a solution.